# Create dummy using category variables more efficiently in SAS

Tags: sas

I have data on with state variation in U.S. Now i want to creat many dummies to control state fix effect. In stata it's an easy work while in sas it seems I have to create all dummies manually.However logit regression with fix effects runs quite slow in stata. I wonder whether there's a more efficient way to create dummy from char variables(not numerical, which I know a few methods to apply) in sas since I have too many char variables need to be created as dummies.
Cheers,
Eva

Comment: Which PROC are you using?  Did you use a CLASS statement?

Answer (score 0):

`proc logistic` supports the `class` statement. Place your variables in the `class` statement and you can specify the type of parameterization you'd like as well. The most common method is referential coding.

```
proc logistic data=sashelp.heart;
    class sex bp_status/param=ref;
    model status = sex ageAtStart height weight bp_status;
run;
```

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect006.htm

Not all procs support the `class` statement, in those cases you can use `proc glmmod` or a variety of other method to create your dummy variables.

http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/02/22/create-dummy-variables-in-sas.html

Comment: Tiny fix: REF should be used without quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to manually create dummy variables you can use a macro like this one. You would need to call it for each variable.

```
%macro create_dummy(dataset=, var=);

  %* Save Distinct Values and Dummy Variable Names;

  proc sql noprint;
    select distinct
      &var,
      tranwrd(tranwrd(trim(&var), " ", "_"), ".", "")
    into
      :value1-,
      :name1-
    from
      &dataset
    ;

    select
      count(distinct(&var))
    into
      :total
    from
      &dataset
    ;
  quit;

  %* Create Dummy Variables;

  data &dataset;
    set &dataset;

    %do i=1 %to &total;
      if &var = "&&value&i" then &&name&i = 1; else &&name&i = 0;
    %end;
  run;
%mend create_dummy;
```

You can add a loop to the Macro if you want to call the Macro only once. Add a do loop to the top like:

```
%macro create_dummy(dataset=, var=);
  %do l %to %sysfunc(countw(&var));
    %let var1 = %scan(&var, &l);

    %* Save Distinct Values and Dummy Variable Names;

    proc sql noprint;
      select distinct
        &var1,
        tranwrd(tranwrd(trim(&var1), " ", "_"), ".", "")
      into
        :value1-,
        :name1-
      from
        &dataset
      ;

      select
        count(distinct(&var1))
      into
        :total
      from
        &dataset
      ;
    quit;

    %* Create Dummy Variables;

    data &dataset;
      set &dataset;

      %do i=1 %to &total;
        if &var1 = "&&value&i" then &&name&i = 1; else &&name&i = 0;
      %end;
    run;
  %end;
%mend create_dummy;
```